# mplayer -msglevel all=-1 doesn't make it completely silent!

Tags: options, mplayer

I'm trying to open `mplayer` to play video without **any** terminal output using this:

```
mplayer -msglevel all=-1 /path/to/video
```

also:

```
mplayer -really-quiet /path/to/video
```

but it doesn't make it completely silent! and these are printed to output:

```
[flv @ 0x9a5d100]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[ass] Init
[ass] Updating font cache
```

How can I make `mplayer` completely silent?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `mplayer file > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I hoped it as an option; but this does the work too;

Answer (score 2):

Bash 4 : `mplayer file &> /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

try this alias

```
alias mplay="mplayer !:1 2>/dev/null"
```

you can then use to the normal mplayer arguments as well, like

```
mplay -playlist myplaylist
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, this is what the MPLAYER_VERBOSE environment variable is for. Set it to -5, no messages.

I don't think it actually works right though. In particular, setting the "fixme" msglevel disables some stuff, and probably results in unwanted output. Setting it back to 5 on the command line may fix that.